# No MediaTypeFormatter is available - Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

This is my first time that I am creating a webAPI file upload. I am using Postman to send the request. The header I have set from Postman is: `content-type:multipart/form-data`

However, I am getting the following error:

> "Message": "The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is
>   not supported for this resource.", "ExceptionMessage": "No
>   MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type
>   'HttpPostedFileBase' from content with media type
>   'multipart/form-data'.",
>       "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",

```
[HttpPost]
public string FileUpload()
{
var r = HttpContext.Current.Request;

return "ok"+r.Files.Count;
}
```